# Softlayer API send SSD disk information?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I send the information of a SSD disk during the create_intance() order?

I see that in the disk information you should send the size of the disk/disks, but I want to send the information that the disk/disks should be SSD and not HDD, that is the default option in the setup.

So I manage to find this:

```
local disk(0)  25,100                                                                                    
local disk(2)  25,100,150,200,300
```

It seems that the only flag that tells me the difference between disks is this 0 and 2, but how can I send this in here:

```
new_vsi = {
    'domain': u'test01.labs.sftlyr.ws',
    'hostname': u'multi-test',
    'datacenter': u'hkg02',
    'dedicated': False,
    'private': False,
    'cpus': 1,
    'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_LATEST',
    'hourly': True,
    'ssh_keys': [87634],
    'disks': ('100',),
    'local_disk': True,
    'memory': 1024,
    'tags': 'test, pleaseCancel',
    'public_security_groups': [12, 15]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to add the flavor in your request, all the valid configurations to order the VSI using the createObject method are displayed by calling the method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/getcreateobjectoptions

when I call that method I can see the following flavor:

```
  "flavor": {
                "keyName": "BL1_2X4X100",
                "name": "BL1.2x4x200",
                "configuration": [
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Computing Instance"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".045",
                            "recurringFee": "29.86",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "2 x 2.0 GHz Cores"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "First Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".006",
                            "recurringFee": "3.98",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "100 GB (LOCAL)"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "RAM"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".054",
                            "recurringFee": "35.51",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "4 GB"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Second Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".012",
                            "recurringFee": "7.96",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "200 GB (LOCAL)"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Fifth Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                            "recurringFee": "0",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "None"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Second Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": ".006",
                            "recurringFee": "3.98",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "100 GB (LOCAL)"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Third Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                            "recurringFee": "0",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "None"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "name": "Fourth Disk"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
                            "recurringFee": "0",
                            "item": {
                                "description": "None"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "totalMinimumHourlyFee": "0.111",
                "totalMinimumRecurringFee": "73.33"
            },
            "template": {
                "id": null,
                "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                    "flavorKeyName": "BL1_2X4X100"
                }
            }
        },
```

you need to pick the favlor more suitable for you and add the template to your request e.g. to adding the flavor to your request:

```
new_vsi = {
    'domain': u'test01.labs.sftlyr.ws',
    'hostname': u'multi-test',
    'datacenter': u'hkg02',
    'dedicated': False,
    'private': False,
    'cpus': 1,
    'os_code' : u'UBUNTU_LATEST',
    'hourly': True,
    'ssh_keys': [87634],
    'disks': ('100',),
    'local_disk': True,
    'memory': 1024,
    'tags': 'test, pleaseCancel',
    'public_security_groups': [12, 15],
    "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                        "flavorKeyName": "BL1_2X4X100"
                    }
}
```

As you mentionated when you pick Balanced Local Storage the disk are SSD, so you need to look for the flavors whose name contains the word BL which stands for Balanced Local.

Comment: Yeah you can, when selection virtual servers, choose Balanced Local and than you have the choice between SSD and HDD.

https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/virtual-servers

Comment: Yeah I'd found the flavor options, but I can't use them because I only want one disk, and the flavors create more than one...

But I see that the way you did you send the information of the disks fixed and add the information of the flavor, I'll test this way and give you a feedback!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears that no matter how many disks you send as information, it has a default creation of 3 disks, all of them appears to be SSD after a few tests, and the disk that you specified will be the main.

Comment: I can see that using the UI there is a message which says "Balanced local storage flavors also require a second disk. For more information, see: Balanced Local Storage" So you cannot have that configuration with only one disk .